# Identificar paginas do site com cadeado HTTPS quebrado

Tags: http, ssl

Estou trabalhar num site e-commerce e notei que algumas paginas estao com o cadeado `https` quebrado e pude corrigi-las. 
Mas nada me garante se existe ou nao outras paginas com o mesmo problema.

Existe uma ferramente pra isso ?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Essa ferramenta apontará o problema nessas páginas: https://www.qualys.com/suite/web-application-scanning/
Ela não é gratuita, mas é a única que já usei. Não sei dizer se há algo parecido gratuito.

Comment: @GeorgeWurthmann essa ferramenta mostra todas as paginas afectadas no site ou analisa uma unica pagina ?

Comment: Todas as páginas. A ferramenta faz o scan de toda aplicação e não apontará apenas os SSL com algum problema, mas qualquer brecha de segurança encontrada.

Comment: @GeorgeWurthmann obrigado ... você sabe se o google analistic também faz isso ?

Comment: O analytics eu acho que não, mas o google tem a ferramenta "CLOUD SECURITY SCANNER": https://cloud.google.com/security-scanner/

Comment: @GeorgeWurthmann a ferramenta parece boa, mas pede montao de informacoes so pra testar !

Answer (score 2):

Essa ferramenta apontará os problemas de SSL entre outros problemas de segurança da aplicação: https://www.qualys.com/suite/web-application-scanning/

Ela **não é gratuita**, mas é a única que já usei. Não sei dizer se há algo parecido gratuito.

Outra opção seria o Cloud Security Scanner do Google: https://cloud.google.com/security-scanner/

Ambas as ferramentas farão o scan da sua aplicação pela nuvem e indicarão as possíveis falhas de segurança, incluindo as de SSL.